# Dynamic initialRouteName in BottomTabNavigator - React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to set a dynamic initialRouteName on my TabNavigator (not even sure if this is the right place to do it), let me explain more clearly.

I have a BottomTabNavigator with 4 items : `Home` (HomeStack), `Explorer` (ExplorerStack), `subscriptions` (SubscribeStack) & `contact` (contactStack). When the app load, with the token I was redirecting the user to my `MainNavigator` (so my BottomTabNavigator) with the initialRouteName `Home`.

```
<Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
 {!token ? (
  <Stack.Screen
    isSignout={isSignout}
    name="AuthStack"
    component={AuthNavigator}
  />
  ) : (
   <Stack.Screen name="HomeStack" component={MainNavigator} />
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

What I want to do now is : when the user is not null and have no subscriptions I want to redirect him directly to the `Explorer` Tab and not the `Home` Tab.

// MainNavigator.js

```
const MainNavigator = (props) => {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 const [subs, setSubs] = useState([]);

 const [fetchData, {data: meData}] = useLazyQuery(USER_ME_QUERY);

 useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
    if (meData) {
      setSubs(meData.me.subscribes);
      setLoading(false);
    }
 }, [meData]);

 if (loading) {
   return <Loading />;
 }

 return (
  <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={subs.length > 0 ? 'Home' : 'Explorer' }
      tabBarOptions={{
        shadowColor: 'transparent',
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: dark ? theme.color.secondary : theme.color.white,
          elevation: 0, // for Android
          borderTopColor: dark ? '#46505C' : theme.color.lightBorder,
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>
            focused ? (
              <Icon size={22} name="home" color={theme.color.primary} />
            ) : (
              <Icon size={22} name="home" color={theme.color.lightGrey} />
            ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Explorer"
        component={ExplorerStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>
            focused ? (
              <Icon size={22} name="columns" color={theme.color.primary} />
            ) : (
              <Icon size={22} name="columns" color={theme.color.lightGrey} />
            ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Subscribe"
        component={SubscribeStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>
            focused ? (
              <Icon size={22} name="sliders" color={theme.color.primary} />
            ) : (
              <Icon size={22} name="sliders" color={theme.color.lightGrey} />
            ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Contact"
        component={ContactStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) =>
            focused ? (
              <Icon size={22} name="mail" color={theme.color.primary} />
            ) : (
              <Icon size={22} name="mail" color={theme.color.lightGrey} />
            ),
        }}
      />
 </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated x
If you need more infos, feel free to ask :)

Thanks in advance x

Comment: Do you have a splash screen??

Comment: Hello @MuhammedYasirMT ! Yes I do have a SplashScreen !

Comment: you can get values of user and subscription before navigators are called. then pass the value to main navigator as props

Comment: so you can hide the splashscreen after all required values are aquired and avoid any other loading like as in main navigator in you file

Comment: @MuhammedYasirMT Thank you for your answer. So if I'm correct, something like this : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props 

So instead of <Stack.Screen name="HomeStack" component={MainNavigator} />, I do this ? <Stack.Screen name="HomeStack">
  {props => <MainNavigator {...props} extraData={meData} />}
</Stack.Screen>

Comment: yes, and use that in MainNavigator  as props.extraData in your case

Comment: Thank You @MuhammedYasirMT for your time ! I'm gonna try to implement that right now :)

Comment: @MuhammedYasirMT Working like a charm ! Didn't know it was that easy :) Thank you very much for the effective answer :)